# Android Binding Library (Xamarin) Zoom Meeting SDK Integration

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mobile-development, zoom-sdk, zoom-meeting

I am trying to Create Android Binding Library of Zoom Meeting SDK for Xamarin. The Part of C# code generated from the .aar file generated issues. The issue is that it genereated duplicate `EventHandler OnSelectVideoEmojiReactionHandler in namespace com.zipow.videobox.confapp.meeting.reaction` and I tried to fix it from MetaData.xml file but could not resolve it. Is there any other way to resolve this issue?

I tried with this code.

```
<!-- Remove the duplicated OnSelectVideoEmojiReactionHandler field -->
<remove-node path="/api/package[@name='com.zipow.videobox.confapp.meeting.reaction']/class[@name='ZmBaseEmojiReactionSendingPanel.IOnSelectListenerImplementor']/field[@name='OnSelectVideoEmojiReactionHandler']" />

<!-- Rename the first occurrence of OnSelectVideoEmojiReactionHandler -->
<attr path="/api/package[@name='com.zipow.videobox.confapp.meeting.reaction']/class[@name='ZmBaseEmojiReactionSendingPanel.IOnSelectListenerImplementor']/field[@name='OnSelectVideoEmojiReactionHandler'][1]" name="managedName">OnSelectVideoEmojiReactionHandlerWithInt</attr>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: please do not post code or errors as images